# Convert C# to php?

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to convert this function from C# to php, but how do I deal with needing to type cast to a byte data type (up to 0xFF) when php only deals with integers?

```
public static byte[] CreateKeyBlock()
{
    byte[] ac = new byte[6];
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        ac[j] = (byte)Rand.Next(0, 255);
        int i;
        byte d;

        ac[3] = (byte)(ac[1] ^ ac[2] ^ ac[4]);
        ac[0] = (byte)((ac[4] ^ ac[1]) + ac[2]);
        ac[5] = 0;
        d = (byte)0xd5;

        for (i = 0; i < 102; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 != 0)
            {
                ac[(i % 6)] = (byte)(ac[(i % 6)] + d);
                d = ac[(i % 6)];
            }
            else
            {
                ac[(i % 6)] = (byte)(ac[(i % 6)] ^ d);
                d = ac[(i % 6)];
            }
        }
    }

    return ac;
}
```

Comment: Byte is also integer number, just has smaller range - so can't see any problem using same code when it's integer in PHP.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: If you copy/paste e.g. `ac[(i % 6)] + d` to PHP without bitwise-ANDing the result with `0xff` then it could go above byte range. If you don't watch out for that, the function will probably not return the equivalent of *exactly six, random* bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CreateKeyBlock()
{
    $ac = '';

    for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++)
    {
        $ac{$j} = rand(0, 255);

        $ac{3} = ($ac{1} ^ $ac{2} ^ $ac{4}) & 0xff;
        $ac{0} = (($ac{4} ^ $ac{1}) + $ac{2}) & 0xff;
        $ac{5} = 0;

        $d = 0xd5;

        for ($i = 0; $i < 102; $i++)
        {
            if ($i % 5 != 0)
            {
                $ac{($i % 6)} = ($ac{($i % 6)} + $d) & 0xff;
                $d = $ac{($i % 6)};
            }
            else
            {
                $ac{($i % 6)} = ($ac{($i % 6)} ^ $d) & 0xff;
                $d = $ac{($i % 6)};
            }
        }
    }
    return $ac;
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. Array indexing uses square brackets, not curly braces.

Comment: @mdm, I know, it's not an array, this returns a string. Please run the code before you say it's incorrect. You will find this is functionally correct.

Comment: Mea culpa, I added whitespace to the post so I could remove the downvote, and upvoted. Note to self: stop reading SO first thing in the morning.

Comment: Actually it's legal to do it [both ways](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). I 'd prefer the square brackets because it's universally recognized syntax for indexing into a collection.

Comment: @Jon, I remember there being some very specific benefits to using the curly bracket notation, but I can't for the life of me remember what if anything they are. Could it be that my mind has made it up? I have the strangest of feelings that it might it self clamp the values to bytes without having to explicitly do so. I seem to remember reading that some where. Although, I should really test for it, and I guess I will once I'm in front of a PHP Parser later today if I remember.

Comment: @MarkTomlin: The values coming out from indexing the string will definitely be in the byte range (PHP's internals treat all strings  single-byte affairs) always. I 'm not sure about the differences between `[]` and `{}` -- I remember reading something that drove me away from `{}`, but not what exactly.

Comment: Interesting, if you ever come across it, and remember my name, do please send that link in my direction.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast anything. Just make sure that any operations that might cause values to get above 255 get their results clamped to the byte range, e.g. by using `$value & 0xff` instead of just `$value`.

It's also worthwhile to consider in what form to return the result -- PHP is not C#, so a string might make more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function CheckByte( $value ) {
    return $value & 0xff;
}

function CreateKeyBlock() {
    $ac = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    for ( $j = 0; $j < 6; $j++ ) {
        $ac[$j] = rand( 0, 255 );

        $ac[3] = CheckByte( $ac[1] ^ $ac[2] ^ $ac[4] );
        $ac[0] = CheckByte( ( $ac[4] ^ $ac[1] ) + $ac[2] );
        $ac[5] = 0;
        $d = hexdec( "0xd5" );

        for ( $i = 0; $i < 102; $i++ ) {
            $ac[$i % 6] = CheckByte( $i % 5 != 0 ? $ac[$i % 6] + $d : $ac[$i % 6] ^ $d );
            $d = $ac[$i % 6];
        }
    }
    return $ac;
}
```

Comment: unless this code is placed into a class the `public static` part is not going to work. It's best just to leave it with just `function`. Secondly, a much faster way of clamping values to byte is by using the bitwise & oparator. This makes your CheckByte function one line long ... `function CheckByte($value) { return $value & 0xff; }`.

Comment: @Mark yes Mark agree, I was using just functions from beginning and before posting I added "public static". I will change it back to functions. And agree to check bytes.